# QGraphicsScene selection order

Tags: python, pyside, qgraphicsitem, qgraphicsscene

When the user selects `QGraphicsItems`, I want to be able to keep track of the order of how they are selected. Right now I'm using `QGraphicsScene.selectedItems()`, but it doesn't give me what was the last selected object.

This seems clear after checking the documentation for `selectedItems()`:
https://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QGraphicsScene.html#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QGraphicsScene.selectedItems

> Returns a list of all currently selected items. The items are returned
>   in no particular order.

So is this something I need to keep track of myself, or am I missing another way to do this?

Thank you!

**Update:**

This seems to work, but may not be the most elegant approach, especially with lots of items. Let me know if I can improve it!

```
def selectionChanged(self):
    if self.scene().selectedItems():
        # Remove any item that was de-selected
        for i in range(len(self.sortedItems)-1, -1, -1):
            if not self.sortedItems[i].isSelected():
                self.sortedItems.pop(i)
        # Add new items
        for item in self.scene().selectedItems():
            if item not in self.sortedItems:
                self.sortedItems.append(item)
    else:
        del self.sortedItems[:]
```

Comment: Seems a reasonable solution... And you are correct about `selectedItems()` not being ordered the way you want. Generally the order matches the order in `items()` which is the order in which items are added to the scene. For a different problem where I needed a sorted items list, I created a map with the `value` being the index in `items()`.